# How to handle second condition in If Else statement

Tags: vb.net

How to handle second condition in If Else statement, My if statement is working but the second condition is not working(ElseIF), Is there something wrong with my condition declaration?

```
Try
            If Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) >= 60 Then

                TextBox7.Text = Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) + 1 & "." & Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1) - 60) & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
                TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox3.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) & "." & Val(TextBox3.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1) - 60) & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")

            ElseIf Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) >= 100 Then

                TextBox7.Text = Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) - 1 & "." & Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1) - 45) & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
                TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox3.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) - 1 & "." & Val(TextBox3.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1) - 45) & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")


            Else
                TextBox7.Text = Format(Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 5)), "##.00") & Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)
                TextBox3.Text = Format(Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 5)), "##.00") - 1 & Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)
                'TextBox3.Text = Format(Val(TextBox3.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0) - 1) & "." & Val(TextBox3.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy"))
            End If
        Catch
            TextBox7.Text = Format(Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 5)), "##.00") & Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @James said + I'd suggest you rewrite to `Select Case` - should be easier to follow:

```
Select Case Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1))
  Case Is >= 100
    TextBox7.Text = Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) - 1 & "." & Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1) - 45) & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
    TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox3.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) - 1 & "." & Val(TextBox3.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1) - 45) & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
  Case Is >= 60
    TextBox7.Text = Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) + 1 & "." & Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1) - 60) & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
    TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox3.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) & "." & Val(TextBox3.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1) - 60) & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
  Case Else
    TextBox7.Text = Format(Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 5)), "##.00") & Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)
    TextBox3.Text = Format(Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 5)), "##.00") - 1 & Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)
End Select
```

Also several points of interest:

- Don't use `Val`, use `Convert` class instead, for example, `Convert.ToInt32`.
- You can wrap `TextBox3.Text.Trim.Split(".")` into a function, and reuse.
- You read the date twice, it's better to read a date once before Select, then do `dateVar.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`.
- Favour .NET syntax instead of VB6. `Val`, `Format`, `Strings.Left` are all VB6. .NET equivalents are `Convert.*`, `ToString` with format string, and `Substring`.
- Control naming - TextBox3 and TextBox7 don't mean anything. Try to come up with a better name for them.

Comment: I Already tried your code but still im cofused my program reads only the second condition which is >=60

Comment: @RomJoy: Yeah, it's supposed to do that. `Select Case` condition actions are mutually exclusive (unlike C++, where you need to include a `break;` statement). Same as If/ElseIf sequence. So, which behavior do you want?

Comment: I dont need the >=100. This one is all I need -> If Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) >= 60 Then... My problem here is, for example. I will input 200 reach 60 and the output will be 140 I reach again the 60 so the output will be 80 then it reach again 60 the output will be 20 and this is the final. I think I just need a return statement so that the cycle of my conditional will just repeating just like in java return statement.

Comment: In my case now with If Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) >= 60 Then example input 200 again then reach 60 and my output will be 140 and the cycle will stop here. It will not continue

Comment: @RomJoy: I don't understand what you mean. If you don't need >= 100 condition, you can remove it.

Comment: but my problem is in decimal, when it reach 100 it will back to 1. But I confused because I have a condition of >=60.

Comment: example 1.50+1.30 decimal reach the 60, output becomes 1.20 which is correct. And If I input 1.60+1.45 decimal reach 60 but the output will become 1.5 which is wrong, the output should be 1.45.

Comment: @RomJoy: Are you doing some kind of mathematical rounding there? It seems like. If you explain what's so special about your way of rounding, I can suggest a better solution. Otherwise use `Math.Round`, instead of your whole `Select Case`.

Comment: Yup I think Im doing rounding. But rounding in decimal point when it reach .60

Comment: @RomJoy: Can you give some test cases in your question? Like "1" becomes "2", "3" becomes "4" etc. The more you give, the better we can understand your need. I think `Math.Round` works with 0.5 as a base point, so everything above that gets rounded up, everything below is rounded down. So adding 0.1 to your number and then using `Math.Round` may do it. There are actually more complicated rules to it, but this simple explanation should cover most of the cases.

Comment: Every decimal that reaches 60. because my problem is when the decimal reach 100 it will continues and cant handle by 60.

Comment: Case1: Example: 1.50 + 1.30 = 1.20 Case2: Example: 1.60 + 1.42 = 1.42 Case3: Example: 1.50 + 1.50 = 1.40 Case4: Example: 1.30 + 1.31 = 1.01. Case 5: Example: 1.60 + 1.60 = 1.60

Comment: Every decimal that reaches 60. because my problem is, when the decimal reach 100 it will continues and cant handle by 60. Like for example 1.60 + 1.60 = 1.120 which is wrong should be 1.60

Comment: @RomJoy: Any common sense grounds behind such arithmetic? Your case 1, for example. 1.50 + 1.30 is 2.80, which 2 rounded down and 3 rounded up. So how did you get 1.20? You can also round the first argument up, or down. Or the second one. But in neither case you will get 1.20. The lowest you get is 2, if you round both arguments down, before the sum. So what are you doing there?

Answer (score 5):

`>= 100` should be the first condition, since it's the most *restrictive*.

`>= 60` should be the second condition, since all values `>=100` are also `>=60`.

Comment: "*since all values `>=60` are also `>=100`*" you might want to rephrase that :)

Comment: My first condition is not working with >=100, still my second condition is working which is >=60

Comment: I tried to rephrase my code but still the program only reads >=60 only. Can you give other rephrase code?

Comment: What is the value of Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1))? Is it > 100?

Comment: In the Condition of >=60, when I reach 60 and above the program will minus(-) 60 And My Condition in >=100 When reach 100 it will minus(-) 46. What should I do because Only one of them is working.

Comment: I dont need the >=100. This one is all I need -> If Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) >= 60 Then... My problem here is, for example. I will input 200 reach 60 and the output will be 140 I reach again the 60 so the output will be 80 then it reach again 60 the output will be 20 and this is the final. I think I just need a return statement so that the cycle of my conditional will just repeating just like in java return statement.

Comment: In my case now with If Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) >= 60 Then example input 200 again then reach 60 and my output will be 140 and the cycle will stop here. It will not continue.